# VBA drop downlist onchange

Tags: excel, onchange, vba

Hey Id like to know if it is feasible : currently I have a drop down list on **sheet1** that contains a list of names being pulled from **sheet2** using data validation. 
The cell next to that drop down list is populated with a phone number using VLOOKUP from **sheet2**.
**My question** : Can I use VBA so that everytime there is a change in the drop down list the cell next to it will become populated from data in  **SHEET2**? keep in mind the value that is selected is needed to pull the proper phone number .

**Why am i asking if my file works?**  Because anyone can accidently delete the VLOOKUP formula and I can not Protect it because it is a shared document that employs several different macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  (Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    Range("B1").Formula = "=VLookup(A1,LookupTable,2,FALSE)"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not seem to work any more.  Using C5, C5:C9, etc. I left it wi ' Cells monitored for changesth the msgbox example code and no pop-up.